# QLess worker code caching

Tags: php, caching, queue

I have Symfony application on my Debian 8 vagrant box which uses QLess (https://github.com/seomoz/qless) for background tasks. QLess backround workers are running by supervisor.

I have an issue that job handlers (symfony commands) are somehow cached.

It's not a NFS problem, source files are identical on guest and host.

The caching problem can solved only by restarting qless workers.

opcache.enable_cli is also set to false in php.ini

Do you have any idea what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was very simple eventually. Worker is a long-running PHP process. All the libraries are permanently loaded in memory after start of the worker, that's why I couldn't see the changes.